# MS Access datasheet won't scroll with scroll bar

Tags: database, odbc, ms-access-2007

I recently converted tables in MS Access from Access tables to SQL.  I have a form with a subform in datasheet view.  The weird thing is, now, when I click and drag the scroll bar, the screen does not update until I let go of the scroll bar.  If I scroll with my mouse wheel it works fine, and everything worked fine before the conversion.

Any clues?  I know MS Access has an ODBC record count parameter in the database settings for displaying field values in a filter.  I'm hoping the soltion for this is similar but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because with the Linked tables (I guess this is what you mean by "converted tables") Access does not retrieve the whole table when you open. It is done for performance. It retrieves just the first chunk and does not know upfront how many rows in the table.

I bet if you do  Access will retrieve the whole table, and then everything will work.

If it is critical, you can do `MoveLast` in the code when you loading the forms. But please note, it will be slow for the big tables